# How to print full backtrace for JavaScript exception?

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception, node.js

When an exception is thrown in my Node.js app, the stack trace printed is limited to a depth of 10. Unfortunately, sometimes this is not deep enough to find the source of the exception. Is there a way to configure Node to print a deeper backtrace on exceptions?

Comment: Maby this could help you? http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ node
> Error.stackTraceLimit
10
```

looks like something you can change at run-time